# Call the global $_GET array values into the value attribute of a field name specified as an array

Tags: php, arrays, get

I am writing a filter function which passes the "Delivery_Date" field as a GET array to PHP to request data from a database.

I am having difficulty determining how to access the GET array variable, "Delivery_Date[>=]",  once it has be converted in the query string. I wish to call it back into the form as the default value using the field name, once the form is submitted.

Once submitted the GET variable is accessed as an array $_GET['Delivery_Date']['>='], however my field names are strings, "Delivery_Date[>=]",  when sent into the getDefault function, therefore not pulling $_GET['Delivery_Date']['>='].

How can I use the field name to call the global $_GET array values into the value attribute of a field name specified as an array?

```
<?php
function getDefault($default, $name) {
if (isset($_GET[$name]) && is_array($_GET[$name])) {
    foreach ($_GET[$name] AS $varkey=>$var) {
        $default = ($var!="") ? $var : $default;
    }
} else {
    $default = isset($_GET[$name]) ? $_GET[$name] : $default;
}
    return $default;
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get" id="filter" >
  <label for="contact">Contact Name</label>
  <input id="contact" name="Contact_Name" type="text" value= "<?php echo getDefault("Search by name","Contact_Name"); ?>">

  <label for="from_date">Date From</label>
  <input id="from_date" name="Delivery_Date[>=]" type="text" value= "<?php echo getDefault(date("Y-m-d"),"Delivery_Date[>=]"); ?>">

  <label for="to_date">Date To</label>
  <input id="to_date" name="Delivery_Date[<=]" type="text" value= "<?php echo getDefault(date("Y-m-d"),"Delivery_Date[<=]"); ?>">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'however my form names are recognized as a strings'? Key of $_GET[ 'Delivery_Date' ] are supposed to be strings.

Comment: Pleas describe by example the desired array/structure that you want to retrieve.

Comment: Yes, but how would you call $_GET['Delivery_Date[>=]']? I wish to use the field name "Delivery_Date[>=]" to retrieve the GET value $_GET['Delivery_Date']['>='].

Answer (score 0):

Try `getDefault(date("Y-m-d"),"Delivery_Date", ">=")` with following function:

```
<?php
function getDefault($default, $name, $subname=null) {
    if (isset($subname)) {
        $default = isset($_GET[$name]) && isset($_GET[$name][$subname]) ? $_GET[$name][$subname] : $default;
    } else {
        $default = isset($_GET[$name]) ? $_GET[$name] : $default;
    }
    return $default;
}
?>
```

Also don't forget to sanitize the output with htmlspecialchars to prevent XSS.